# On desktop sized browser, the images are shrinking too small instead of wrapping the line

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of an issue and I'm hoping someone can point out my mistake.  I have been investigating what could be causing the issue but I cannot identify the culprit myself.

I have a website design that shows a set of i'mages with some text over it.  (Note: dev work is not fully complete).  The idea is to have the i'mages always appear at the same height, but when there are too many of them, the next set should drop to the next row.

While I have this working on a tablet sized browser window (you can see this by making your browser smaller while looking at the page below), the full size browser window on my desktop refuses to wrap the line.  Making it look ugly.

Any idea how I can get these i'mages to wrap the line on my full size desktop browser?  I'm a little frustrated at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your objective, but I tried few things:

- remove the fixed height on the images container (guess its 'reel'
- add fixed width to your images, so they will drop down to the next line depending on the size of the screen

Hope it helps